# How do I load data from a third party database that has its own API (it has an API Search EndPoint) to implement with my azure web app bot?

Tags: c#, rest, botframework, azure-bot-service, azure-qna-maker

First time posting. How do I load data from a third party database that has its own API (REST API) which has an API Search Endpoint to implement with my azure web app bot? All I need is to get the search functionality from the database (users type in queries in the search bar of a third party website and the relevant results are displayed to the user by extracting data from the database that the website uses to get information from.) I need to implement this search functionality with my azure webapp bot which is developed in C#. Currently my web bot used the QnA maker as well.

Would really appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Are you trying to load the data (make a copy of the data in your database) or trying to "get the search functionality" (does their API have a search endpoint)?

Comment: I am trying to get the search functionality and yes, their API does have a search endpoint.

Comment: It might be a good idea to [edit] both the title and the question to reflect that and to include any information about the API search endpoint. Also please include a [mre] showing what you've tried and where you are stuck in using that endpoint.

Comment: So the thing is, I have the get methods for the exact search functionality that I need which I got from Postman, now I just don't know how to make use of that get method which essentially gets all the data that I need from the database to implement with my azure webapp bot in C#. I just don't know where to start with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have a look at this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client

The example in that document instantiates an HTTP client object like this, though it's up to you if you want to use `static` or any other modifiers on the field you declare:

```
static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
```

You can see that the HTTP client is used for GET requests like this:

```
static async Task<Product> GetProductAsync(string path)
{
    Product product = null;
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(path);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        product = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Product>();
    }
    return product;
}
```

The important parts there are `client.GetAsync` and `response.Content.ReadAsAsync`.

This is a fairly minimal example that doesn't include things like authorization headers and such. You can have a look at the [Microsoft.Bot.Connector](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/tree/master/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Connector) namespace and especially [Conversations.cs](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/master/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Connector/Conversations.cs) for more advanced examples of HTTP requests.

Comment: Thanks so much Kyle. Really appreciate the help. I have successfully implemented this with the HTTP client yesterday. I am now having issues integrating this with the QnA maker but that is a separate question that I would post here.

Comment: @user458622 - I'm glad to hear that your issue was resolved. Please remember to upvote and accept my answer.